# Is there a prewritten low-impact time drop down that allows selection of any of the 1440 minutes that there are in a day?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, drop-down-menu

I will probably be writing my own.. I wanted to check if anybody already knew of one.

There will be multiple time drop downs in a single form. They will **not** be `<select..>` tags with 1440 options per select... They will have a default scrolled position, and they will **look** like a single drop down with 1440 items but will only display the scrolled position's items and the individual items will only be stored for the focused dropdown.

Comment: A `<select>` with 1440 items? Argh. Why not split this into two drop-downs `0..23` and `0..59`?

Comment: We don't want to split them because there would have to be AM PM . That makes three drop downs. The users we are dealing with would prefer a drop down to typing and we want to have a default scrolled position without a default value.

Comment: I had this same problem. I decided that it is faster for an untrained person to simply enter "1:44 pm" in a text field rather than a clicky UI. I suggest that you use a widget that also enables direct entry of the time, many users will prefer it. I could see more of a benefit if the user is limited to specific minute values rather than the full 0-59 options.

Comment: "We don't want to split them because there would have to be AM PM " either use Larry Ks suggestion or use a 24 hour clock. Every new recruit in the military figures it out on the first day, I'm sure your users can too.

Comment: 24 hour clock FTW. Never understood why anyone wants to stick with AM and PM... it's just confusing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with an input that opens a list of 20 links showing different times. The top and bottoms had previous/next links that *looked* like page up and page down functions. The middle of the list was either the currently selected option or the current time.

Answer (score 3):

1440 items in any drop-down list is ill-advised. Especially if there are more than one of them on a page.

Why not look for some other time entry control?

- http://keith-wood.name/timeEntry.html
- http://pttimeselect.sourceforge.net/example/index.html
- http://haineault.com/media/jquery/ui-timepickr/page/

... or break it down into 2 selcts - 1 for the hour and 1 for the minute

Comment: I said they would ***look*** like 1440 items,, but they would not _actually_ have that many elements.

Comment: The second link looks like I good idea. I will put that in for consideration.

Comment: Well, then I'm not sure what you're asking - how does an element look like it has 1440 items, but not?

Comment: An artificial scroll bar would be one way,, or an element that is way tall to take up the space of the elements that don't exist.

Comment: Still not 100% clear. If you're just trying to get a time input, it seems to me that you're over-complicating the process, or trying to reinvent the wheel - unless you need something super-specific that these don't offer.

Comment: @cjavapro, the problem is that a dropdown that looks like it has 1440 elements will totally unusable, no matter how it is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

A drop-down with 1440 entries just isn't going to be usable.

How about a normal text box so that users can just type the time they want, quickly (and the input will still work without JavaScript), coupled with up/down spin controls if you need that:

```
<input type="text" class="spin-time" value="00:00">

<script type="text/javascript">
    // Find and apply to elements with class `spin-time`
    //
    var inputs= document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i= inputs.length; i-->0;)
        if (inputs[i].className==='spin-time')
            addTimeSpinner(inputs[i]);

    function addTimeSpinner(input) {
        input.onchange= function() { alterTime(0); };
        input.parentNode.insertBefore(makeButton('-', -60), input);
        input.parentNode.insertBefore(makeButton('+', 60), input);
        input.parentNode.insertBefore(makeButton('+', 1), input.nextSibling);
        input.parentNode.insertBefore(makeButton('-', -1), input.nextSibling);

        function makeButton(label, d) {
            var button= document.createElement('input');
            button.type= 'button';
            button.value= label;
            button.onclick= function() { alterTime(d); };
            return button;
        }

        function alterTime(d) {
            // Parse time value, default to 00:00 if doesn't make sense
            //
            var mins= 0;
            var match= input.value.match(/^(\d\d):(\d\d)$/);
            if (match!==null)
                mins= parseInt(match[1], 10)*60+parseInt(match[2], 10);

            // Add time difference, wrapping round
            //
            mins= (mins+d+1440)%1440;

            // Format back to hh:mm string
            //
            input.value= padLeft(Math.floor(mins/60), 2, '0')+':'+padLeft(mins%60, 2, '0');
        }
        function padLeft(v, n, c) {
            v+= '';
            if (v.length>=n) return v;
            return new Array(n-v.length+1).join(c)+v;
        }
    }
</script>
```

This is 24-hour. Altering the code to parse and produce the 12-hour clock format (including the horrid wart of getting 12 AM and PM the right way around) is left as an exercise for someone who doesn't completely hate the idea of the 12-hour clock and want to see it eradicated from the Earth.

Comment: `an exercise for someone who doesn't completely hate the idea of the 12-hour clock and want to see it eradicated from the Earth` IAWTC.

Answer (score 0):

I would use HTML5 and:

```
<input type="time" />
```

And perhaps add a jQuery time picker thing if needed. But for the most part I seriously find it quicker to just type in the time rather than find it in a list of some sort. Just make sure you validate and have some easy to read error messages, et cetera...